# How to securely use Azure Key Vault?

Tags: azure, public-key-encryption

I am using Azure Key Vault to store and access a secret in my Unity game. I have set up the Key Vault and used the following parameters in my code:

```
clientId
clientSecret
tenantId
vaultName
secretName
```

Is this a secure way to store my data? Or do I need to obfuscate or encrypt these parameters somehow to prevent hackers from decompiling my game and accessing the secret?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you saying you are shipping those values as part of your client code? Then of course, people could decompile your code and see the service principal secret.

Generally speaking: Not a good idea. I would not distribute the credentials of a Service Principal to clients, or just anywhere outside of my control. If your app has some sort of server component - that the clients are presumable somehow authenticating against - then have that act as a proxy to your Key Vaults (or any backend services, really)

Comment: Thanks.  Key Vault will retrun my api key in my game. i think it's no safe .